# What is the # for when formatting using %s

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I came across this example of an assertion and was wondering what the `#` is for:

```
#define ASSERT( x ) if ( !( x ) ) { \
    int *p = NULL; \
    DBGPRINTF("Assert failed: [%s]\r\n Halting.", #x); \
    *p=1; \
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

It is the "stringize" preprocessing operator.

It takes the tokens passed as the argument to the macro parameter `x` and turns them into a string literal.

```
#define ASSERT(x) #x

ASSERT(a b c d)
// is replaced by
"a b c d"
```

Answer (score 4):

`#x` is the  stringification directive

`#define Stringify(x) #x`

means  `Stringify(abc)` will be substituted with `"abc"`

as in

```
#define initVarWithItsOwnName(x) const char* p = #x

int main()
{
   initVarWithItsOwnName(Var);
   std::cout << Var; //will print Var
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`#` is the preprocessor's ["stringizing" operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx). It turns macro parameters into string literals. If you called `ASSERT(foo >= 32)` the `#x` is expanded to `"foo >= 32"` during evaluation of the macro.

Answer (score 2):

It's a preprocessor feature called [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification). It

> replaces [the macro parameter] with the literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant.

Answer (score 2):

`#` is the stringizing operator defined in Section 6.10.3.2 (C99) and in Section 16.3.2. (C++03)

It converts macro parameters to string literals without expanding the parameter definition.

> If the replacement that results is not a valid character string literal, the
>   behavior is **undefined**.  The order of evaluation of # operator is **unspecified**.

For instance, syntactically, occurrences of the backslash character in string literals are limited to escape sequences.

In the following example:

```
1        #define  mkstr(x)  #  x
2        char  *p  =  mkstr(a  \  b);  
       /*  "a  \  b"  violates  the  syntax  of  string  literals  */
```

the result of the `#` operator need not be `"a  \  b"`.

Comment: Are there any circumstances under which "the replacement that results is not a valid character string literal"?  I can't think of any.

Comment: @James McNellis : Found an example in "The New C Standard", check out my post.

Comment: Interesting. My understanding of "the spelling of the preprocessing token sequence" (from C++) is that the compiler needs to perform any necessary escaping, so `mkstr("a")` would yield `"\"a\""`, not `""a""`. Perhaps that does not apply to extraneous non-whitespace tokens?

Comment: No that doesn't get applied to extraneous whitespace tokens. This would be fine IMHO `mkstr(a\b)`. No exraneous whitespace.

Comment: @Prasoon:  What I meant was that `\` on its own is a "non-whitespace character" token.  It's not an operator-punctuator and doesn't fit into any of the other preprocessing token types.  So it seems that the only time the behavior could be undefined is when you have a preprocessing token that cannot be converted into a token after preprocessing (there is no preprocessing token-to-real token mapping for non-whitespace character tokens).

Comment: While I agree about the example producing undefined behavior, I find it curious:  my understanding was that the stringize operator was responsible for fully escaping tokens that needed to be fully escaped, e.g. `"\\"` becomes `"\"\\\\\""`.

Answer (score 1):

It's the stringizing operator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you see is called *stringification*. It allows you to convert an argument of a macro into a string literal. You can read more about it here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html.